# phpMyAdmin mysql saved Emoji as Question mark

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, emoji, utf8mb4

I want to save Emoji into MySql database, and I realize, three bytes Emoji is saved correctly in the database, but 4 byte emoji have been saved as question marks. It seems like I did fully  convert utf8 to utf8mb4, but I dont know what exactly is missing here. My MySQL version is 5.5.29, when I do a `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` in  MySql shell, it shows the following:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

Now, for testing purpose, I only have 1 database with 1 table created to test emoji saving. I created the database through phpMyAdmin, and created the table through MySql shell:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_emojis` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and it still does not work (still question marks).

However, I found something interesting, I see question marks in phpMyAdmin, but I can see emoji icon properly in Mysql shell if I type select * from test_emoji; any ideas?

Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your client (phpMyAdmin) actually connects to the server using the utf8mb4 charset? Repeat your above query from within phpMyAdmin

Comment: Hi, Michel, thanks for your remind, I figured out that too, my myphpadmin is actually still using utf8, that's why I cannot see it on the phpmyadmin client, but able to see it on MySQL shell. However, I am having a new question here. Please read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488503/ios-cannot-decode-emoji-unicode-in-json-format-correctly-and-emoji-icons-are-di

Answer (score 3):

phpMyAdmin has hardcoded `utf8` charset so you would have to edit it's code to change this. For future versions it's fixed in [fb30c14](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/fb30c148f22f3e1534cb216a5994660b09c70795) (this shows you also where to change these values).

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your phpMyAdmin to >= 4.3.9 and problem solved.