# IOS cannot decode emoji unicode in json format correctly, and Emoji icons are displayed as squares

Tags: ios, encode, json, emoji, utf8mb4

I am working on an iPhone app which allows people to send messages with Emoji icons. I saved the icon in Mysql with charset utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci, and all the emoji icons is saved correctly in my database. However, when I return json back to the client (php json_encode), the Emoji is encoded as something like this: '\ud83d\ude04', and iPhone displays it as a square. However, if I return as XML, the Emoji Icon won't become unicode like this: '\ud83d\ude04', it will just be the icon.

I am wondering if this is an issue on my server, or on my client. If it is my client, how can object c decode it correctly.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: You are delivering data to your iOS client using an XML webservice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`"\ud83d\ude04"` is the JSON Unicode escape sequence for `U+D83D U+DE04`, which is the "surrogate pair" for the Unicode U+1F604 (SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES).

But `NSJSONSerialization` decodes this correctly, as can be seen in the following example:

```
const char *jsonString = "{ \"emoji\": \"\\ud83d\\ude04\" }";
NSLog(@"JSON: %s", jsonString);
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:strlen(jsonString)];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
self.myLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"emoji"];
NSLog(@"Emoji: %@", self.myLabel.text);
```

*Output:*

```
JSON: { "emoji": "\ud83d\ude04" }
Emoji:
```

and the Emoji symbol is also displayed correctly (tested with iPhone device and Simulator).

Comment: This solves my problem and it works perfectly. The way I parse the json response is: initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding; I guess since the unicode for Emoji is not utf8, I should not use utf8Encoding to validate it. However, initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding does not seem to work either. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user2002692: `initWithData` converts `NSData` to `NSString` and does not know anything about JSON and therefore does not convert "\ud83d\ude04".

Comment: How do you do this in swift?

Comment: @MartinR How did you get the unicode escape sequence from the Emoji? Is there a tool?

Comment: @Isuru: I don't remember how I did it. I think in earlier OS X versions, the "Character Viewer" showed the surrogate pair for characters outside of the basic multilingual plane, but I cannot find that anymore in the "Emoji & Symbols" view in the current OS X. – However, it is easy with Swift: `print("".utf16.map { String(format: "%04x", $0) } )`

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: @Isuru you can find complete list of emoji in unicode escape sequence [here](https://github.com/shanraisshan/EmojiCodeSheet)

Answer (score 8):

Please follow following steps:

- Convert Emoji characters to base64 and send to server using Json.
- On server side save base64 in database without decode.
- When you want to display Emoji on Application then retrieve same base64 data from server.
- Decode retrieve string and display on app.
- Your Emoji character will display properly.

Note: When you want to Show on webPage then Decode data when you display data on WebPage.

Answer (score 0):

Our team fixed this problem by transfer utf data to server, saving them in mysql utf8mb4 codepage and receiving with base64. Server convert saved data to base64 on demand.