# convert emojis into unicode dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios

How should i convert the emojis into unicode and send it to server and then can decode it dynamically.

I can statically give the if condition for perticular emojis.But i want to make it dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635393/ios-5-how-to-convert-an-emoji-to-a-unicode-character and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488503/ios-cannot-decode-emoji-unicode-in-json-format-correctly-and-emoji-icons-are-di

Answer (score -1):

few days ago i have same problem. i tried this its work for me :

to pass value to the server

```
    NSData *data = [textView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *goodValue = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    goodValue = [goodValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
```

when fetch value from the server

```
    NSString *goodValue = [StaticClass urlDecode:[dataDict objectForKey:@"comment_text"]];
    NSData *newdata=[goodValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *mystring=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:newdata encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```