# send emoticons to my webservice

Tags: android, serialization

I am trying to send emoticons to my webservice but I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character (d83d)  at
>   org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.reportInvalidCharacter(KXmlSerializer.java:144)
>     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.writeEscaped(KXmlSerializer.java:130)
>     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.text(KXmlSerializer.java:536)    at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.DM.writeInstance(DM.java:68)     at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:656)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:649)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:595)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:573)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:658)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:555)
>     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:205)     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:134)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:149)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
>     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
>     at corcanoe.gps.tracker.MyClass.MyFunction(MyClass.java:708)

This is the code I use for MyClass.MyFunction():

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
request.addProperty("MyText", MyText); //MyText has emoticons
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SOAP_VERSION);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //I get the error here
Object result = envelope.getResponse();
String resultData = result.toString();
return resultData;
```

It works for a few simple emoticons like ☺ but it doesn't work newer ones like crying or laughing. So, the question is, how can I serialize properly?

Comment: you need to use UNICodes for Emojis

Comment: Thanks. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/28273410/3303075