# Cant Display Emojis From Server in textview Android

Tags: android, textview, android-json

I want to display the emojis which are in `json` object in android. 
Right now I am getting some square shapes on `textview`.

[image]

Comment: post your json for more better understanding

Comment: I have added a picture in which there are emojis.. I want to display them in android textview.. @Akshay Katariya

Comment: are you testing in which device ? Android version?

Comment: Android Version 6  (Marshmallow)

Comment: what you are getting in string ? when you receive from server? can you post that ? i am not talking about above image

Comment: U want to see the url ??\

Comment: No ! , i want see actual response received at android side ! Can you do debug?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28273410/6925888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly set emoji in `TextView` 
Either you can use this  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html

add this in gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-emoji:27.1.0"
}
```

Implement this in your application code

```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     FontRequest fontRequest = new FontRequest(
       "com.example.fontprovider",
       "com.example",
       "emoji compat Font Query", CERTIFICATES);
       EmojiCompat.Config config = new FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(this, fontRequest);
       EmojiCompat.init(config);
   }
}
```

and change your `TextView` to  `android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView`

You can check this if you have any doubts https://github.com/googlesamples/android-EmojiCompat

or

You can try unicode directly like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894146/3111083

Comment: But I want the emojis from url

Comment: and also want to play the mp4 file which also contains emojis in VideoView

Comment: I am also talking about android TextView. So your question is how to extract the string from url ?

Comment: No, I am getting the string but instead of getting the url i am getting some square shapes in place of emojis

Comment: Ok the URL is a different question , for displaying title in textview you can use EmojiCompat.

Comment: When are you seeing this squares?. When you set this title in textview right ?

Comment: Yes in text view

Comment: Ok then try my first method . It should fix that issue.

Comment: I did changed my textview to android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView but after that the app is crashing

Comment: From where i can generate certificate ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167688/discussion-between-pooja-pachchigar-and-sunil-sunny).