# Imported emoji in mysql table and json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, json, wordpress

I copy MSSQL table to mysql table using (dbconvert.com)
All the emoji in the SQL SERVER ( טוב) set in mysql like that (טוב����).

It wasn't a problem until I was trying to do json_encode to a query that include emoji in this text.

This is the code  problem:

```
echo json_encode($forumPage);
```

**I don't have problem inserting emoji My problem is the old convert from mssql**

.

**Some things I had tryied**

1) adding

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

2) using

```
   json_encode($forumPage,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

3) using (this is Wordpress site)

```
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
```

**Some extra info about my DB:**

```
   SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%'
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_database       | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_server         | utf8mb4            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

[image]

Comment: Please follow it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16543713

Comment: @ChaimsDev that my problem how to convert the emoji in mysql db

Answer (score 2):

You need to change collation to 'utf8mb4_bin'
And also set charset for the mysql connection as:

```
$database_connection = new mysqli($server, $user,$password,$database_name);
```

$database_connection->set_charset("utf8mb4");

Please refer: [Storing Emojis in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)

Comment: I don't have problem inserting emoji My problem is the old convert from mssql

Comment: Thanks save my day set_charset("utf8mb4") works for me

Comment: Works perfectly for me.